# How can I keep a FIFO open for reading?

Tags: linux, bash, mkfifo

I'm trying to redirect a program's stdin and stdout. I'm currently experimenting with a bash mockup of this, but I'm getting some odd behavior.

I have the following:

```
mkfifo in
mkfifo out
```

I also have the following script, test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo "I read ${line}"
done < /dev/stdin
```

In terminal 1, I do the following:

```
tail -f out
```

In terminal 2, I do the following:

```
./test.sh < in > out
```

In terminal 3, I do the following:

```
echo "foo" > in
echo "bar > in
```

However, instead of seeing "I read foo" followed by "I read bar" in terminal 1, I get nothing after the first echo, both lines after the second echo, and then the test.sh program in terminal 2 exits. How can I prevent the exit so I can keep sending test.sh input? Also, instead of buffering and then dumping when the program terminates, how can I get the output from test.sh to flush to the tail -f in terminal 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the redirection on a single compound command that contains your two `echo` commands.

```
{
  echo "foo"
  echo "bar"
} > in
```

If, as seems likely on a closer reading, you want `in` to stay open while you are executing commands interactively, use `exec` to open `in` on another file descriptor:

```
exec 3> in      # Open in on file descriptor 3
echo "foo" >&3  # Write to file descriptor 3 instead of standard output
echo "bar" >&3  # "
exec 3>&-       # Close file descriptor 3
```

Note that `exec 3> in` will block until something (`test.sh` in your case) opens `in` for reading, and due to buffering, you may not see any output from `tail -f out` until you close file descriptor 3.

Comment: The latter is exactly what I was after-- thank you!